# Post-build events in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator

Is it possible to have post-build events (as in VC++) in Qt Creator? In particular, I would like to copy the executable to a different folder after it has been built. Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find here all the variables you can use in your project file (.pro): [http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html).

The one you are searching for is: [`DESTDIR`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#destdir)

Anyway, in QtCreator you can customize all the build and link operation by adding/removing instructions in the Project tab.

Comment: You can also use [QMAKE_POST_LINK](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-post-link) in your. .pro file, which couples it closer to the .pro file than the Project Build Settings. But it only runs when the link triggers, not every time you fire the build.

Answer (score 6):

Add execution of a script to copy the files as a build step as below,
[image]