# QTCreator copy files to output directory with INSTALLS

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator, qmake

I have two sub directories `docroot` and `config` in my Qt project. Files in these directories shall be copied to the build directory whenever I build / debug the project.

As of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3991210/356726 this is possible by using `INSTALLS` ([QtDoc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#installs)), which seems to be much easier than running copy command (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3984180/356726)). A similar approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6776872/356726).

```
config.path    = $${DESTDIR}/config
config.files   = config/*
docroot.path   = $${DESTDIR}/docroot
docroot.files  = docroot/*
INSTALLS       += config docroot
```

However, when I run a build in Qt Creator nothing happens. This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6292967/356726) says I need to run `make install` . Can I somehow trigger / do this from within Qt Creator automatically whenever I build. I would need always the latest version of the files.

EDIT: Eventually I have used `$$OUT_PWD` instead of `$$DESTDIR`

Original comment from Logan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058744/356726):
"Just a note: I used `$$OUT_PWD` instead of `$$DESTDIR` to make it work. For reference `$$OUT_PWD` is the folder that the program is built to, and `$$PWD` is the folder that the program is Being built from -in other words it's where the .pro file is."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need is a custom build step.

1. Switch to **Projects** Mode: press Ctrl+5.
2. On **Build Settings** tab under **Build Steps** click on **Add Build Step**.
3. Choose **Make** from the menu.
4. Write **install** into **Make arguments:** text input box.

(The version where I checked these is Qt Creator 2.4.1.)

Comment: Your part is correct, thanks. I still only have a problem with $${DESTDIR} not being set (thought it is automatically set to the build dir), tried %{buildDir} as well with no success. So have to figure the right var out.

Answer (score 6):

I was using Shadow Build on Window 7 and I ran into the same problem than you.

Moreover, after setting my `INSTALLS` and running make install I was having the following message :

> Nothing to be done for `install'.

The reason is that you have to set $$DESTDIR yourself.

In my case I wanted to copy *.qml files, that's how I achieved it:

```
# if you are using Shadow build, you need to get the output folder
CONFIG(release, debug|release): DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/release
CONFIG(debug, debug|release): DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/debug

# if you are using normal build (non-shadow) that would have worked as well.
CONFIG(release, debug|release): DESTDIR = release
CONFIG(debug, debug|release): DESTDIR = debug    

QmlFiles.path = $$DESTDIR/Qml
QmlFiles.files += $$files(Qml/*.qml)

INSTALLS += QmlFiles
```

**EDIT :**

I figure out that `$$OUT_PWD` can be use to find the Shadow Build Output path. So, I fixed the code which finally come close to what you were using.