# How to build and install QtRemoteObjects on windows and qtcreator(use vs2013 compiler)?

Tags: qt

After install perl, I could build remoteobjects.

But qtcreator didn't build repparser. I see it "copy /y ....\lib\Qt5RepParser.dll ....\bin", but can't find this file.

And didn't generate files like: plugins.qmltypes, qmldir.
I don't know how to install this module into qt folder.

I just want use this module like this: Qt += remoteobjects.

Answer (score 0):

My remoteobjects could work now. Here are my steps:

1. git clone QtRemoteObjects
2. open qtremoteobjects.pro
3. switch to release mode
4. cancel Shadow build in project page.
5. add step "Make install"([Here is detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593165/qtcreator-copy-files-to-output-directory-with-installs/11598991#11598991))
6. build src/remoteobjects
7. build src/repparser
8. build tools/repc
9. build src/imports
10. build features

I have to build them seperately. Seems build all project at one time lead errors, like:  [sub-repparser-make_first-ordered] Error; [sub-src-make_first] Error....

These steps works fine with Kit Desktop MSVC.