# Installing dependencies with Qmake using INSTALLS variable

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have a project and I am using following lines to move an xml file to my executable directory.

```
xmls_to_move.path = $${OUTDIR}
xmls_to_move.files = somefile.xml
INSTALLS += xmls_to_move
```

I can check that qmake sees the file, CTRL and clicking it navigates to it. But for some reason, it does not move the file after build. What might be the reason?

Comment: you need to run INSTALL as make target:    make install

Comment: Is there a way to make qmake automatically issue a `make install` after the build?

Comment: custom build step is designed for this, like answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11598991/2266412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run INSTALL as make target: make install.
If you want it to be run automatically you can add it as custom build step, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598991/2266412).